# BibTex does not include publisher in Book

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Why does the following BibTex-entry not include the publisher?

```
@book{billingsley,
  title={Convergence of Probability Measures},
  author={P. Billingsley},
  year={1968},
  publisher={Wiley, New York}
}
```

There is a warning that the journal is empty, but yeah, it is exactly how I have copied it from google scholar, so I have no idea what to do.

The output is only title, author, and year.

What can I do? Sorry, I am a beginner.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{memoir}

\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

text \cite{billingsley}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}


\end{document
```

Comment: Well, it may be due to many factors. I do not know what bibliographic style you're using. Could you add please a full MWE?

Comment: thank you for trying helping me. I am really a beginner, so I am not sure of what I should post a minimal working example. Only of the bibtex or of the whole file?

Comment: The problem is that for some books the publisher is included whereas for others it is not.

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) should illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is **when we see compilable code**, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please read the link.

Comment: thank you for your help and your patience. I've read the link. The problem is, that I am working with a huge template. 
But I tried to add a MWE to the post. I hope that helps.

Comment: You can also take the bibtex entry from the [publisher's site](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470316962) directly instead of Google scholar. They are more likely to be in the correct format that publisher wants to be cited with.

Comment: thank you for the hint, I will remember this. But in this case, I am not interested in the second edition, but in the first one, and this is, to my knowledge, not published online.

Comment: There's no entry in the bibliography of your MWE because there are no `\cite` commands in the body of the document. Add the instruction `\cite{billingsley}` and you'll get a corresponding entry in the bibliography. If you use the `plain` bibliography style, the `publisher` field *will* be included in the typeset entry. By the way, the `@book` entry type doesn't recognize or process the field type `journal`. A separate question: What's the reason for specifying the `OT1` option when you load `fontenc`? (This option is still the default in most TeX distributions...)

Comment: Thanks Mico for your answer. I have no idea, as mentioned above, I work with a template provided by my university. 
Including this instruction does lead to outputting the corresponding entry, that is true, but it does not include the publisher, only the other data.

Comment: @user136457: comment aside, since you use `utf8 input encoding` you should load `soulutf8` instead of `soul`.

Comment: thank you bernard, I changed it to soulutf8. 
Can someone tell me, whether there is a problem, if I change the entry from book to article? Because then the same structure including the publisher works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To long for a comment.

I have reduced your MWE to the following code, running without errors and returns the desired result.  My system here is MiKTeX 2.9, updated yesterday.  Styles `plain`or `alpha` do not change the publisher output.

Which tex districution do you use?  And are youre packages up to date?  You can check this by adding a `\listfiles` before the `\documentclass ...` and compare the resulting list in the log file with this:

```
 *File List*
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX document
  memoir.cls    2013/05/30 v3.7b configurable book, report, article document class
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
   mem11.clo    2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 11pt size option
mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
   babel.sty    2014/03/24 3.9k The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
no-publisher.bbl
```

The shorted MWE is:

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{billingsley,
  title     = {Convergence of Probability Measures},
  author    = {P. Billingsley},
  year      = {1968},
  publisher = {Wiley, New York},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

text \cite{billingsley}. 

\bibliographystyle{alpha} % plain
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

And the result on my system is:

[image]

Please run **exactly this MWE** on your computer and compare your results with mine.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
my babel.sty, english.ldf, inputenc.sty are not up to date. 

But the output is exactly the same..

Comment: Okay. In the MWE we saw the publisher.  I guess now you have a bib entry before `billingsley` causing an error. If you find this error and correct it the bib entry `billingsley` should work.  Please have a look in your file `.blg` and search there for error messages or warnings.

Comment: you are right. I forgot to put a comma in an entry before. unbelievable. Now it works perfectly!

Thank you for your help! This did not only help me to find the error but also to get used to the process of error finding, e.g. checking the file list.

Thank you very very much for that